# Can you make a if statement with time and date as

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Is it possible to make an If and AND statement that will show a specific day if the time and date follows?
Like for example 2/13/2021(3 am) up to 2/14/2021 (3:00 am) be counted as 2/13/2021?
And it will automatically the same thing will happened with 2/14/2021 3:01 am and so on?

I was think of using if and now() but I have no idea how to code it and if today ends will the dates that are currently in the cell changes too?

Thank you in advance
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R7dnbN7UAtZ-uC6Knwp6YKAqW-K3EW34jORBXbemg7Y/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A1:A3-3/24, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Comment: How does it work? If I link it to now() will it be auto-generated? Anyway thank you this is a great info for me

Comment: @BunnyBunny it takes a value from A column and takes away 3 hours from it. so basically it will just move the "midnight window" 3 hours in the past. you can think of it as custom timezone

Comment: Got it thank you I read A1:A3 -3/24 like dividing on something I guess I'm not familiar with array yet

Comment: 3hours divided by 1day(24h) = 0.125 is the value of 3hours